# how to deal with "the unknown unknown"

Tags: knowledge

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiPe1OiKQuk

alot of people make fun of Rumsfeld for the "unknown unknowns", but i'm wondering how a person like him would start to try to get his hands around the "unknown unknown". With known unknown, you can probably setup a strategy to explore the unknown.

My question is how does a person deal with the unknown unknown? This obviously affects decision making on a subject matter. how do you approach that problem?

I'm not sure how to tag this question.

Comment: I suppose one issue with Rumsfeld's point is that the distinction between "known unknowns" and "unknown unknowns" is not wholly clear.  Is the reason that we know that we do not know something that we can logically determine what it would be for it to be true, but simply lack sufficient evidence for it?  If that is what we mean, then a logical positivist, for instance, would say that because "unknown unknowns" are outside of logical verification conditions, there simply aren't any. (ctd)

Comment: There's another possible interpretation of the phenomenon. We are currently working with a standard **model** for the evidence that we have available. Within this model we have some uncertain events which we can model probabilistically (known unknowns). But it's possible that this model is not a good fit for actual events.  If that's the case then events may occur that our model has not taken into account (unknown unknowns).  To understand the "unknown unknown" then is to study the application and limits of models in science: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/models-science/

Comment: No idea if this is anything at all philosophically relevant as regards an answer to your question, but it might be a good launch point for a refinement. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if there's any philosophers that have written on this subject itself, as opposed to knowing things in general.

Practically, Phillip Armour wrote an [article about the levels of ignorance](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=352194):

- 0th Order Ignorance: Lack of Ignorance. I have 0OI when I (probably)
  know something.
- 1st Order Ignorance: Lack of Knowledge. I have 1OI
  when I don't know something. With 1OI we have the question in a
  well-factored form.
- 2nd Order Ignorance: Lack of Awareness. I have
  2OI when I don't know that I don't know something.
- 3rd Order
  Ignorance: Lack of Process. I have 3OI when I don't know a suitably
  efficient way to find out I don't know that I don't know something.
- 4th Order Ignorance: Meta-ignorance. I have 4OI when I don't know
  about the Five Orders of Ignorance.

The first level of ignorance is what people normally refer to. Rumsfeld referred to the second level: there were questions that he didn't know the answer to because he didn't know the question in the first place.

Comment: This answer is about the psychological of unknowns, ignorance and incompetence, and I wish I'd thought of including some of that. I like the levels, even though the "4th order" should better be reformulated in a less memorization-of-arbitrary-authority-figure's-classification way. I think the two other main things things to be aware of here are the power of conformity, as a human instinct and as a group effect, and the [Dunning-Kruger effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect). That makes 3 subjects on the psych side of things. Too lazy to update my answer, though. ;-)

Comment: Interesting answer. Although the last order sounds like the author jerking his own chain. Really? The highest order of ignorance is not knowing his theory? Haha come on. Am I interpreting this right?

Comment: I really like the answer despite the 4th order. I think the 3rd order is because an answer to my question. Basically setup a process of discovery for awareness (2nd order) then go from there.

Comment: I've read before that the 4th order of ignorance is tongue in cheek, but does have a point - there are evidently people (eg those referred to by OP) out there who are unaware that there are levels of ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a zillion different unknown unknowns. E.g. suddenly a giant TV set might drop from the sky. One prepares by estimating probabilities for various kinds of unknowns, and concentrating the effort on the least unlikely. The dropping TV set is very unlikely, to the point that it would be counter-productive to waste time and resources on preparing for it.

Unknowns of the kind "almost zero probability but almost infinite impact if occurs" are also best disregarded. Multiplying the near zero probability by the near infinite impact if occurs, to get an expected impact value, doesn't really work in this case. Very small differences in the numbers can produce very different expected values, so there's no real information about probability to be had. E.g. Blaise Pascal (contemporary of Descartes) used an expected impact value argument to apparently prove that one should better believe in a specific god. But it's in the nature of near-zero-probability things that there are zillions of in principle possible such things, so e.g. Pascal's argument failed when other possible gods were considered.

For computer belief management dealing with unknowns involves representing both probability and support. For example, 50% chance of raining tomorrow with 100% support means that in half the cases, it will turn out to rain. But with 0% support it doesn't mean anything: no prediction is possible, and the probability must just be ignored. At least one theory that attempts to do this correctly, Dempster-Shafer evidence combination, suffers from combinatorial explosion, i.e. it's just impractical. Apparently one can not, in practice, get a completely correct picture of the world. Happily very rough approximations work well in practice. But that means that we in some cases will end up with doing the Wrong Thing, where if we but had infinite memory and processing capacity, would have enough info to do the Right Thing; hence the expression "20-20 hindsight".

Comment: @anonymous serial downvoter: Please do explain your downvotes. That way the answers can be improved, or others can at least learn about your view, or, people can more easily dismiss you. Thanks.